# How to perform a subselect query with findAll

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm tring to discover if there is some way to perform a 'findAll' with *sequelize* that will let me do the equivalent of "find me all of the customers that have ANY orders with a cost > $100" or "find me all of the customers where ALL of the order have a cost > $100".

So assuming a schema where each 'Customer' has a *hasMany* 'orders' property, I was ideally looking for a syntax like:

```
Customer.findAll( { where: "orders" { any: { cost: { gt: 100 }}}}
```

or

```
Customer.findAll( { where: "orders" { all: { cost { gt: 100}}}}
```

But this obviously won't work with the current bits. So... how can I accomplish somethig like this?

Answer (score 3):

```
Customer.findAll({ include: [{ model: Order, where: { cost: { gt: 100 }}]});
```

By adding a where to the include, the query will be an inner join.

Comment: So does this return all Customers that have at least one order that has a cost > 100 along with only the associated orders that meet this criteria (i.e. a subset of all of the orders for this Customer).  If so, if I now want not just the customers but also all of the orders for 'any' customer with any orders with a cost > 100, do I need to execute another query.  i.e. what I really think I need is an 'exists' subselect.

Comment: Hi @JayTraband have you solved it? I am facing the same problem :(

Comment: No, I still have the issue.  I really think that we need some way to build an exists subselect ( as mentioned above).